# Java - Could a return statement be used to exit a program?

Tags: java, return

In Java, could `return` be used in the `main` method to exit the program, instead of using `System.exit()` (or by just letting the `main` method finish all its tasks)? I know that nothing noticeable happens when I exit a program using `return`, but are there any side-effects that occur as a result, like the program not terminating completely?

I know that this seems like a trivial question but I looked at other posts on Stack Overflow and online for info on this topic but seemingly couldn't find anything exactly similar that answers the question.

Comment: Similarly, you can `return;` from any method/function with a `void` return type.

Comment: @JohnHenly Yeah, I know that. I was just wondering specifically with the 'main` method if there were any side-effects in using `return` to exit.

Comment: I guess these people don't buy your statement about doing a lot of prior research (and no, I didn't downvote).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing `return` from the `main()` method will exit the whole program.

---

Caveat: If you start (non-daemon) threads, the JVM will wait for those threads to finish before shutting down.

Answer (score 2):

`return` marks the end of the method.
`System.exit()` terminates the program.

In other words: `System.exit()` will stop all running tasks and end the process. `return` in a `main` will still wait for the tasks to finish before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

For a little peace of mind, I wrote a test program to see what would happen:

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
      {
         if(i == 10)
            return;

         System.out.println(i);
      }
   }
}
```

This prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```